# How to make Visual Studio open external include files

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2019

I'm working on a C/C++ project in Visual Studio 2019 and all files are included as such:

```
#include "header.h"
```

Everythings working code-wise and I can open most include files through ctrl + left mouse click as usual. However, when it comes to external files not in the project folder (which are found on compilation and don't produce an error in the text editor mind you) the file "wasn't found in the current source file directory or build system path", I have to go open it manually in my file explorer if I want to see the content.

Hence I was hoping there would be an option within VS or the C/C++ extension to make VS open the files on ctrl + left click.

Comment: `#include "header.h"` means look in the project folder first. Then if not found in the project folder look through the system folders and the folders listed in the `c/c++->General->Additional Include Directories` setting.

Comment: Are you asking about Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code? They are very different and probably one of the tags is wrong.

Comment: [similar problem (bug) here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Go-To-Document-F12-for-C-include-st/1191078) was solved internally.   If your version is more than two years old, consider updating it

Answer (score 1):

This problem seems to have sprouted from the newer Cmake version 3.26.2 cause the other team members with older versions didn't have this problem and after adding

```
set(CMAKE_NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED ON)
```

to the mix and reloading the VS project files it worked just fine.

It was NOT solved by just adding <> brackets instead of "" quotation marks around the include file like I assumed at first.